# How do I determine if a particular key is unique in a multimap?

Tags: c++

I have a `multimap<key_type,value_type>` and I would like to know if a particular key appears in the map at most one time.

I know I can call `multimap.equal_range(key)` to find an iterator to the start and end of the range containing `key` but I would like to know if there is only one element between the `range.first` and `range.second`.

Is there a better way than incrementing the `range.first` value to see if it is equal to `range.end`? Since `multimap::iterator` is bidirectional it's not a huge deal to undo the increment but it seems sloppy to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you check if the [std::multimap::count(key)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/count) == 1?

Comment: Ah, hadn't seen the `count` overload.  Perfect. I'll confirm it works tomorrow and mark as answered.

Comment: @LarryOsterman Must `"key"` be in quotes? I liked it without quotes since `key` could be a variable. @Nawaz Thanks for the better reference site link

Comment: No it doesn't - this was my bad, in my case the key is a string and I spaced. I'll undo.